# Will this give me a Median in SQL

Tags: sql, median

Will this give me the median for each company?

```
SELECT a.id,a.company_name,a.salary
FROM (SELECT id,company_name,Salary,PERCENT_RANK OVER() (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY Salary) AS 'percentile') a
WHERE percentile = 0.5
GROUP BY a.id,a.company_name
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily.  The problem is that `percent_rank()` returns a floating point number.  And floating point comparisons are quite dangerous -- because floating points are fuzzy.

Why not just use `percentile_cont()`?

```
select distinct a.company_name,
       percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by salary) over (partition by a.company_name) as median
from a;
```

I'm pretty sure that any database that supports `percent_rank()` also supports `percentile_cont()` and `percentile_disc()`, although the exact syntax could vary among databases.